# How to get the spider name in Scrapy pipeline outside of the process_item function?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I've written a few spiders that pull similar data from different sources. I've also written a pipeline that allows this data to be put in a database. I want to be able to use the same code for multiple spiders to output to different tables, named dynamically from the spider name.

Here is the `pipeline.py` code:

```
class DbPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    """
    Initialises database connection and sessionmaker.
    Creates table if it doesn't exist.
    """
    engine = db_connect()
    create_output_table(engine)
    self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def process_item(self, item, spider):

    """
    Saves scraped products in database
    """

    exists = self.check_item_exists(item)

    if not exists:
        session = self.Session()
        product = Products(**item)
        try:
            session.add(product)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()


    return item

def check_item_exists(self,item):

    session = self.Session()
    product = Products(**item)

    result = session.query(Products).filter(Products.title == item['title']).first()

    return result is not None
```

And here is the `model.py` file:

```
    DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

def create_output_table(engine):
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

def db_connect():
    """
    Connects to database from settings defined in settings.py 
    Returns an sqlalchemy engine instance
    """

    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))

class Products(DeclarativeBase):
    """Sqlalchemy table model"""
    __tablename__ = "name"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String(200))
    price = Column('price', String(10), nullable=True)
    url = Column('url', String(200), nullable=True)
```

What i'm trying to do is get the `__tablename__` variable to be the same as the spider name, which I can easily do in the `process_item` function as it is passed a `spider` object and can use `spider.name` and assign it to a class variable, however the function will run after the table is created/defined. How can I go about getting the spider name outside of the `process_item` function in the `pipelines.py` file?

Edit: I've tried the solutions listed in [How to access scrapy settings from item Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075941/how-to-access-scrapy-settings-from-item-pipeline) however access to the 'settings' doesn't give me access to the attributes assigned to the current spider running. I need to dynamically get the name of the spider based on what spider is running the pipelines. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access scrapy settings from item Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075941/how-to-access-scrapy-settings-from-item-pipeline)

Comment: @gangabass hey, i've updated my question with why it's not a duplicate

Comment: do you want to get current spider name in your `check_item_exists`?

Comment: If I could just get that name anywhere in that file it will be something, but I need it to really be in the class Products. I'm currently trying out how to use the from_crawler() from the post you linked method but i'm not entirely sure it will help. I know crawler.spider.name might work, but not sure if this will just return the DefaultSpider name and not the currently running one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to get current spider name in your `create_output_table`:

```
class DbPipeline(object):


    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.spider.name)

    def __init__(self, spider_name):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_output_table(engine, spider_name)
        ......
```

and (in `models.py`):

```
def create_output_table(engine, spider_name):
    # now you have your spider_name
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The problem here is that Scrapy process your `models.py` file **before** your `pipelines.py`. So you need to find a way to generate your SQLAlchemy model later. You can use this thread as a starting point: [`Dynamically setting __tablename__ for sharding in SQLAlchemy?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163911/dynamically-setting-tablename-for-sharding-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: This is perfect, I was half way there. Thank you so much for this.